# Python: convert from INT to BYTES issue

Tags: python, micropython

there is some strange while converting from INT to BYTES.
the function i used to convert: (int).to_bytes(byte lenght,'big')
in my specific cases i tried to convert 31 to Bytes, it showed:

```
b = (31).to_bytes(1,'big')
b
b'\x1f'
```

but when i convert the 10 or lager than 31. it will show another unexpected value:

```
b = (10).to_bytes(1,'big')
b
b'\n'
==> b value here supposed to be: b'\x0a'. i don't know why it return b'\n' please let me know the secret behind.
```

same with value 50.

```
b = (50).to_bytes(1,'big')
b
b'2'
==> b value supposed to be b'x\32'
```

Please help.....

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. `b'\n'` means the same thing as `b'\x0a'`, and `b'2'` means the same thing as `b'\x32'`. The way Python represents the `bytes` object to you is just the canonical form. It's the same as how if you set `s = "hi"`, the value of `s` reported back to you is `'hi'` with single quotes instead of double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python represents `bytes` in such a way that if a value is printable ASCII, it will use that instead of an escape sequence. You can try it out:

```
>>> b'\x0a'
b'\n'
>>> b'\x32'
b'2'
```

And it checks out: `\n` is Python's escape sequence for newline (ASCII character 10), and `2` is ASCII character 50.

Comment: Thanks Jasmijn.
it's work. although it show b'2' but i sniff the package. the value still same b'\x32'.
currently i'm using micropython to send bytes Over onther device.